# How do you upgrade a database schema with InstallShield?

Tags: database, schema, installshield

I am using InstallShield to install a SQL Server DB, and the applications that use it. Now I need a way to go back and say, ok, v 27 of the database now needs moved to 28. I have the alter scripts, and I know based on a table which version any given DB is. How can I make InstallShield do this?

Answer (score 1):

I used a C# form app to do this that is launched from installshield using LaunchAppAndWait

This app runs alter scripts that are complied in as resources.

Answer (score 0):

I used install shield and couldn't find anything on the web so here's my 2c to help someone in a similar scenario.

You can mark scripts with versions in install shield.
Install shield then creates an install shield table in your db to track the db version
A script will not be executed unless its > the schema version.
Works fine once your db connection is pointed at the db. 
So if you need another script to create the Db I suggest you create the db in your connection that points to master.

Then create another connection to your sql server pointed at the db and do all your versioning in this script.
More here:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/ISQLSchemaVersion.htm